# slurm controller busy a lot of times when used by other users

Tags: parallel-processing, slurm

I am fairly new to SLURM: the grid I use has many different users and when they are submitting or canceling jobs, it seems that other users are not able to query partition status, etc. This is extremely frustrating especially when creating jobs that spawn other jobs since they end up failing because the controller is busy. Does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default settings, Slurm can get slow/hang when many users submit/modify/cancel many jobs at the same time, especially with backfill and accounting enabled.

See tips to improve on that in [these slides](http://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm_ug_2012/SUG_Oct2012_HTC.pdf) from the Slurm User Group Meeting of 2012.

Comment: please note that i am not a sysadmin.. is there anything that i can do as a user?

Comment: other than reporting it to the sysadmins every time it happens, I don't think there is much you can do. You can try and make your scripts more robust by retrying failed submissions. Or you can try submitting many jobs with dependencies at once (when things are working smoothly) rather than having one job spawn other jobs.